# What's the derivative of a map defined on manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, definition

I'm going through Warner's book on differentiable manifolds. On page 8 he defines what it means for a map $f: U \subset M \to \mathbb R$ to be differentiable:

$f$ is differentiable iff $f \circ \psi$ is differentiable for all charts $\psi$ on $M$.

He does not proceed to give a definition of the derivative of $f$. I tried to do a web search but did not find a definition. Is the derivative of $f$ just defined to be the derivative of $f \circ \psi$?

> What's the definition of the derivative of a map defined on manifolds?

**Edit**

At the bottom of page 105 in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=xQsTJJGsgs4C&lpg=PR1&dq=introduction%20to%20manifolds&pg=PA107#v=onepage&q=introduction%20to%20manifolds&f=false) (in the proof of the regular level set theorem) the author calculates the Jacobian of a map $F: M \to N$. This Jacobian contains entries of the form ${\partial F \over \partial x_i}$. So, it seems to me that the derivative, at least partial derivatives exist (although a comment below by Mariano Suarez-Alvarez suggests otherwise)

Comment: Do you know about tangent spaces?

Comment: Any differential topology book will tell you. For instance, take Bredon, Hirsch, Janich etc.

Essentially, the derivative is a linear map between the tangent spaces. Depending on the way you defined the tangent space, you will look at this map in a different way, but all of them are equivalent (or sort of... some definitions are not equivalent if you are not on a $C^{\infty}$ manifold with $C^{\infty}$ functions.)

Comment: There is no such thing as a derivative of a function $f:M\to\mathbb R$. What there is, though, is a differential of such a function at a point $p\in M$, which is a map $\mathrm d_pf:T_pM\to\mathbb R$. Warner surely tells you what it is!

Comment: @ArpitKansal Kind of.

Comment: @astudent: then it's time to read about the *tangent bundle*.

Comment: The tangent bundle or tangent spaces? These comments seem to suggest that it is possible to define a derivative whereas Mariano's comment suggests that it isn't.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo So you're saying one can define a derivative? Mariano seems to say that one cannot in his comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function from a manifold M to the manifold $\mathbb{R}$. Also, let $\gamma$ be a smooth curve on the manifold $M$ with $\dot{\gamma}\in TM$ it's derivative.

Then, we define the derivative map of $f$ as the function that does the following
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
      Df : TM & \rightarrow T\mathbb{R},\\
            \dot{\gamma} & \mapsto df(\dot{\gamma})=\dot{\gamma}(f)= \dot{(f(\gamma))}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same answer as @ser969547's.

Given a point $p \in M$ and a tangent vector $v \in T_pM$, the directional derivative of a smooth function $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at $p$ in the direction $v$ is defined to be
$$
D_vf(p) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\gamma(t)m
$$
where $\gamma$ is a smooth curve such that $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$. This definition is independent of coordinates. You can check that, with respective to any set of local coordinates, it is the standard definition of a directional derivative for a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Moreover, using coordinates you can verify that if you fix $p$, then
$$ v \mapsto D_vf(p) $$
is a linear function of $v$. This map is called the differential of $f$ at $p$. It is the appropriate definition of the derivative of $f$. If you write this out in local coordinates, you get the familiar formula that, if $f$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then
$$
D_vf(p) = v\cdot\nabla f(p).
$$
Therefore, $df$ is the coordinate-free version of the gradient.